# How to know the position of IME and display to user if it's currently being used on another display

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-automotive

I am currently working on an android app which will be used on Car's dashboard for different displays. My requirement is to display to user a dialog showing that IME is being used on another Display(Screen) on different one if it changes it's focus.

Can someone suggest, how to proceed on this?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer, if there is one, may depend a lot on what sort of Android environment this is. Are you using Android Automotive, for example?

Comment: Yes, currently developing for Android Automotive.